# Azure Worker Role Deployment for background data

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

I want my application to be in 2 phases. 1 part will simply fetch data in json format from an API and store it to a SQL database(or maybe a NO-SQL) and the other half(the web part) will read the data and implement customize alerts. So, basically i need to create a worker for the fetch process. But I'm confused between worker role and web role in Azure. Kindly help me what's the best possible way to implement this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just merge both in the same web role - the part of code running in IIS (the ASP.NET project created when you create a web role from a Visual Studio template) will handle web requests and the part running the "role entry point" will run the fetch process. Unless you absolutely need to scale them separately this will give you a simpler and more manageable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I have run into some problem here. I sort of wanted to create a WEB API(RESTful) in ASP.NET and then use it for all the purposes. So web role was fitting in perfectly. But, can you help me with some resource where should i start to develop an API that returns a JSON response.

Comment: I don't really have any experience with "web api" projects - the stuff we have is a plain old "ASP.NET MVC3" app. I guess if you search for "how I return JSON from a web api application" that will do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this tutorial? It gives possible use cases and tutorials for both web and worker roles.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-storage-1-overview/

Comment: Can you be a little more specific because I want the architecture wise idea not the coding part.